# JSQ Messages Attribute

Tags: ios, xcode

can anyone help fix my error? I've been fixing it for hours and still nothing ill appreciate anyone who help.

```
didPressSend(_: UIButton!, withMessageText: String!, 
              senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!)

    print("didPressSend")
    print("\(text!)")
    print(senderId)
    print(senderDisplayName)
    messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, 
                    displayName: senderDisplayName, text: text!))
    print(messages)
}
```

That line of code been giving me  trouble. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is error? add error to question

Comment: didPressSend(_: UIButton!, withMessageText: String!, 
              senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!)

    print("didPressSend")
    print("\(text!)")
    print(senderId)
    print(senderDisplayName)
    messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, 
                    displayName: senderDisplayName, text: text!))
    print(messages)
}

Comment: same error I'm getting trying to run the app

Comment: Any way to fix this?

Comment: Tou just pasted the code into the comment. This doesn't show any errors. Please show the actual error message. One question though - is this method an `IBAction`?